# How to setState a specific value of a particular parameter in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

```
this.state = {
  array: [1, 2, 3],
  objects: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
}
```

How can I change the specific value of an object or array in the state without setStating the whole array/object?

something like

```
this.setState({ array[2]: 5 })
this.setState({ object[0].id: 0 })
```

Comment: There are some options to do it, but basically it's important to understand that this is not a stupid obligation, but it's done in ReactJs by purpose, to mark this object as a changed object to cause new render.

Comment: Trying to understand your intention. You sounded like intentionally mutating the object/array?

Comment: You do not mutate the state in React. It is a bad practice, you always replace it with new one.

Comment: I cant really understand the rationale of `without setStating the whole array/object?`

Comment: Do like this, this.setState({...this.state.object, object[0].id: 0 }).It will replace the object with new one.

Comment: @Isaac I was meant to copy the whole object/array. Thanks to the community now I know my mistake.

Comment: @blueedge: No problem, we learn something new everyday :)

Comment: Have you seen this? https://immerjs.github.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a helper function to set an element at an index and return that newly updated array

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3]
const object = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]

const setElementAtIndex = (index, value, array) => [
  ...array.slice(0, index),
  value,
  ...array.slice(index + 1)
]

console.log(setElementAtIndex(0, 99, array))
console.log(setElementAtIndex(1, 99, array))
console.log(setElementAtIndex(2, 99, array))
console.log(setElementAtIndex(0, { ...object[0], id: 0 }, object))
```

```js
this.setState({ array: setElementAtIndex(2, 5, array) })
this.setState({ object: setElementAtIndex(0, { ...object[0], id: 0 }, object) })
```

Comment: I thought of that initially but I tried finding a more efficient way. I tried finding an inbuilt method for this ( if exist). Is there any better way other than just duplication the whole object

Comment: IMO, when working with array and object, we should return a copy (at least shallow one) of the updated to avoid mutation

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const state = {
     array: [1,2,3],
     objects: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
}

const newArray = state.array.map((v, i) => i === 2 ? 5 : v);
const newObjects = state.objects.map((v, i) => i === 0 ? {...v, id: 0} : v);

console.log(newArray);
console.log(newObjects);

// this.setState({ ...this.state, array: newArray });
// this.setState({ ...this.state, objects: newObjects });
```